# Ayuda con proyecto en visual studio en asp.net y c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Muy buenas me gustaría saber si alguien me podría ayudar con este proyecto que tengo error.
Consiste en conectarme a la base de datos(la tengo con char los campos), lo cual todo bien, pero cuando genero en el botón consultar sin nada me funciona bien, el problema es cuando ingreso algún código de consulta, ahí me sale el error, alguien me podría decir en que estoy fallando.  este es el código del botón.

```
      using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

        namespace FacturacionCompras
        {
            public partial class Formulario_web11 : System.Web.UI.Page
            {


                protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                protected void btnConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (TextCODProveedor.Text == "")
                    {
                        lblMensaje.Text = "Debe de ingresar un cod de proveedor";
                        TextCODProveedor.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!CADFacturacion.CADProveedor.ExisteProveedor(TextCODProveedor.Text))
                    {
                        lblMensaje.Text = "Proveedor no existe";
                        TextCODProveedor.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    CADFacturacion.DSFacturacion.PROVEEDORDataTable miProveedor = CADFacturacion.CADProveedor.GetProveedor(TextCODProveedor.Text);
                    foreach (DataRow row in miProveedor.Rows)
                    {
                        TextNOMBRE.Text = row["Nombres"].ToString();
                        TextDIRECCION.Text = row["Direccion"].ToString();
                        TextPAIS.Text = row["pais"].ToString();
                        CalFecha.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Fecha"]);
                    }

                    lblMensaje.Text = "Proveedor Consultado";
                }

    // este es el codigo siguiendo el CADProveedor
    using CADFacturacion;
    using CADFacturacion.DSFacturacionTableAdapters;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


    namespace CADFacturacion

    {
        public class CADProveedor
        {
            private static PROVEEDORTableAdapter adapter = new PROVEEDORTableAdapter();



            public static DSFacturacion.PROVEEDORDataTable GetProveedor(string COD_PROV)
            {
                return adapter.GetProveedor(COD_PROV);
            }

            public static bool ExisteProveedor(string COD_PROV)
            {
                return adapter.ExisteProveedor(COD_PROV)== 1;//en esta parte tengo mis dudas ya que es un boolean.


            }

// Después de consultar me genera el error y me manda aquí
using System;

namespace CADFacturacion
{
    internal class CADProveedor
    {
        internal static DSFacturacion.PROVEEDORDataTable GetProveedor(string text)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        internal static bool ExisteProveedor(string text)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En donde realizas la consulta? por que en GetProveedor llamas a una función con el mismo nombre en su interior?

Comment: la consulta la realizo en "proveedordataTable" a través del adapter. no se si me di a entender o yo entendí mal.